# Why is location transparency called location transparency?

Tags: database, distributed-system

What is the reason behind this name?

I thought the word transparency means you can see it. So you can see the location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When something is transparent, as a glass, you can see through it, what is on the other side. So, in some sense, anything which is transparent is invisible.

Location transparency means that in a network you refer to a resource by using a symbolic name, instead of its location (for instance its logical or physical address). So the location is actually transparent (invisible), and you can relocate a resource to a different location, without changing its name, so to no disrupt the systems that use that resource through its name.